# Nested Logistic Regression in SAS

Tags: nested, sas, logistic-regression

I'm trying to model outcomes of 2 binomial variables that I don't believe to be independent of one another.  I had the idea of nesting the outcomes of one variable within the other like this:

[image]

but I'm unsure of how to go about this in SAS.  Otherwise is it acceptable to use multinomial regression and make dummy variables to compare groups without nesting? the two variables appear related but there's other variables were interested in looking at significance for

Comment: I'd probably use a multinomial regression using 4 different levels for the new variable to be able to compare them. I'm assuming you've checked correlation and chi square on these outcomes already to confirm a preliminary relationship.

Comment: Ya preliminary analysis found an association, I just wasn't sure I could use multinomial regression if the outcomes weren't completely independent.

Comment: There's also ordinal regression if there's a known hierarchy of the outcomes? I think this is where some Subject Matter Expertise would come in making that decision.

Comment: Programming questions are on topic here, but you should post your code - at least your basic "this is what i'd do if they're not nested" code.  Otherwise, you might be better off on [stats.se] instead, where the more stats-y questions can be answered.